# Same short url mapped to different long url on goo.gl

Tags: php, analytics, goo.gl

How can I tell goo.gl to generate same short url for a different long url ?

Let's say i have goo.gl/wbn0 points to www.marin.com

What I need is being able to have same short url goo.gl/wbn0 point to www.rusi.com for instance.

This way I can track the short url.

Comment: wouldn't it be a collision that opens the way to scams and redirects through short urls?

Comment: Is it possible to add an extra parameter to the curl command to achieve that? I can't get goo.gl to generate the same short url.

Comment: May be you could say to use user-defined short URL fro their API.